# Not able to start a development server using npm start

Tags: ios, iphone

I've been getting this error saying 'Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?'

Tried to add expo using yarn and installing again but it did not work. [This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOs3n.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using node js version higher than v17, which is required for npm package `expo-cli`. You can check your node version using `node -v` and then either downgrade or look at something called `npx expo`. It is all written in the warning message, I guess it will help to google it as well.